# Cannot drop table from schema

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to use a simple "Drop Table" Statement in PL/SQL Developer on some tables, but they won't drop. The tables are quite large, but I've never had this problem before. After over half an hour, this error is returned: *ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object*. Things that I have tried:

- Restarting PL/SQL Developer
- Deleting other tables (My schema is not full and have previously had a lot less space)

Comment: Some other session has a lock on the table because it is doing something with the table.  You can see in `v$session` who is blocking your session and determine what to do based on that (potentially you have another session which is blocking the session that is trying to drop the table, perhaps there is an application that still uses the table, etc)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I ran a select statement on v$session but the table does not exist. Is this the correct way to access v$session columns?

Comment: If you haven't been given access to the data dictionary, you'd need to work with your DBA either to get access or to have them determine who is blocking your session.

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. PL/SQL Developer is a desktop application for working with Oracle. I think you might be mixing them up.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

to find sid: `select * from v$locked_object;`

to find serial#: `select * from v$session where sid= "sid_from_the_previous_query";`

to kill session: `alter system kill session 'sid, serial#';`

Or if you are just one user just try commit or rollback.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I ran the select statement but the table does not exist. Do you know why this is, or what else I can do?

Comment: If table doesn't exist you don't have enough privileges to read it. Please login as sys or whatever; or grant select to these views to you.

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll be waiting on IT for access over the weekend. Is it possible to try commit or rollback without this?

Comment: Just try to do it.

Comment: @JHARR the session holding the locks has to commit or roll back to free its locks. You can't do that from the blocked session, short of killing the other session or cancelling its SQL which requires ALTER SYSTEM privilege and details about the other session.